# Quick release adapter with handle bar

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod, quick-release

I'm planning to buy a MeFoto Roadtrip Air. But its head cannot be replaced and it has an arca-swiss quick release plate. I prefer a spring loaded quick release plate and searched for an adapter and found things similar to [this one](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/554141-REG/Manfrotto_323_323_RC2_System_Quick.html).
But I would further prefer if it had a handle bar; something like those video heads have (that we use to move the camera by hand).
So in a nutshell I'm looking for a 'spring loaded (don't know the exact name) quick release adapter with a handle bar attached to it'. I googled "quick release adapter with handle bar" but there aren't any results that are relevant for me.

p.s. Is the qr adapters's qr plate replaceable? If it could I would replace the qr plate with a qr plate with a D-ring screw, that's why.

Comment: Search again with the word *clamp* not *handle-bar*, that is for bicycles :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need any fairly small, lightweight [video head](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JIQ17I0) with a quick release plate on the top of it. Most heads have a 3/8" hole in their base so you may need a [3/8" to 1/4" bushing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BJW3082) insert to attach it to the arca style plate on the [MeFoto Roadtrip Air](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LXYFI6L).

The biggest problem you're going to run into is that the MeFoto Roadtrip Air is very lightweight. That's good for portability and travel. That's not so good for stability and camera control.

If you're only shooting stills the normal solution is to use a remote (wired or wireless) or timer mode to separate the force of operating the camera and the motion that induces from the time when the shutter is open. But if you are wanting the video head with a "handlebar" so you can pan while shooting video you may find that the tripod itself will not be stable enough to do what you want. This becomes even more of an issue when the center column is extended for additional height. Adding the weight of another head to the top of the tripod will only compound the stability issue.

The other thing to consider is that on the whole, arca style plates are generally considered superior and more rigid than QR plates such as the Manfrotto RC2 system. They also allow for front-to-rear adjustment to better balance the camera/lens on top of the tripod. This is particularly an advantage with a lighter weight tripod.

If you really want a video type head you might also consider the [Benro Aero 2 Aluminum Video Travel Angel Tripod](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NFXNXYE). Benro/MeFoto are the same company. The tripod is [designed more as a video platform](https://fstoppers.com/originals/i-asked-mythical-video-travel-tripod-and-benro-made-it-reality-aero-35556) from the ground up. It is a bit heavier than the Roadtrip Air but the weight of the detachable video head is already included in the weight of the Aero 2.

Comment: +1 on the suggestion for a dedicated video head. Just adding a long handle to a plate on top of a ballhead does not make the head a controllable pan-tilt head (the long handle would do nothing to prevent the camera from flopping sideways to the left or right from on top of the ball mount).